# Lock name and location of linked workbook in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, links

I have two Excel workbooks that I manage on my local network. The first workbook, let's call it Book A, is located on the network, is only editable by me, and contains data that is used in the second workbook. The second workbook, which I'll call Book B, is local to each user's computer and uses data from Book A to help my users perform some calculations. This arrangement allows me to update the data used by all my users from a single location without having to mess with Book B. But occasionally, I need to make changes to the way Book B handles or displays the data from Book A, add/remove columns, etc. This is where my problem occurs.

To update Book B, I'll go into each user's computer from my workstation over the network. However, whenever I open a user's copy of Book B to make the changes, it automatically updates its link to Book A to a local working copy on my machine, instead of the official master copy on the network. I have to manually re-point Book B to the correct instance of Book A, every single time. I've tried turning off the automatic updating of links, but that hasn't helped. So, my question has two aspects:

1. Why is Book B automatically latching onto my local copy of Book A whenever I update Book B, and;
2. Is there a way to lock or permanently set the filename and path of Book A that I want Book B to use, to prevent Book B from automatically 'updating' its link to a completely different file?

Comment: Where is Book A stored?  Do the users copies of Book B reach out to your machine to access Book A?

Comment: Book A is stored on a network drive. There is only one copy of Book A that should be available to users. Book B is supposed to link to the copy of Book A on the network. However, I keep a local "play copy" of Book A on my machine, and whenever I edit Book B on a user's machine, it's this local copy that gets referenced.

Comment: Rename your play copy to something else and make sure it's not open when you edit Book B.  Or don't use a play copy at all.